# Create a link to a file containing the percentage sign

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url

I'm creating a MVC3 web application in C#.
I have to implement a search screen to display data from a SQL database and a picture corresponding to these data.
In my Details page I have created a link to this document:

```
        @{
        string fullDocumentPath = "~/History/" + Model.PICTURE_PATH + "/" + Model.PICTURE_NAME.Replace("001", "TIF");
    }
    @if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(fullDocumentPath)))
    {
        <a href="@Url.Content(fullDocumentPath)" >Click me for the invoice picture.</a>
    }
```

The problem is that the system who created the documents (and added a reference to their path in the database) chose to use the % in many of the files names.
When I have this link:`http://localhost:49823/History/044/00/aaau2vab.TIF` it is ok. When this link is created: `http://localhost:49823/History/132/18/aagn%8ab.TIF` it fails with:

```
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Requested URL: /History/132/18/aagn�b.TIF
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

use [Url.Encode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.encode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to escape scpecial characters:

```
@{
   string documentDirectoryPath = "~/History/" + Model.PICTURE_PATH + "/";
   string documentName = Model.PICTURE_NAME.Replace("001", "TIF");
}
@if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(documentDirectoryPath + documentName)))
{
  <a href="@Url.Content(documentDirectoryPath + Url.Encode(documentName))" >Click me for the invoice picture.</a>
}
```

Comment: it creates something like `http://localhost:49823/BusinessCaseHistory/Details/~%2fHistory%2f132%2f18%2faagn%258ab.TIF`, which results in a HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

Comment: Right, then you'll have to encode only the name part of the string

Comment: This time it gives me `http://localhost:49823/History/132/18/aagn%258ab.TIF` and then the HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request. If the file name is altered, then it can't be found. I fear I'll have to rename all files and records from the DB (around 402k of them).

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to access is not URL-encoded. You can only use ASCII-characters, so for special characters you need to UrlEncode your path. You can see a list of these characters, and the corresponding ASCII-character in this list:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

You can convert your path-string to be URL encoded using the UrlEncode method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

And if you want to decode it again, you can use the UrlDecode method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

Comment: As far as i understand, not only names in db, but also files in filesystem have name with % in it, so if you'll try to decode name you'll end up with wrong name.

Comment: In the Database I have the path to my file in a column (like '132/21') and the file name in another column (like 'aagn%8ab.001'). So, no url to decode first.

Comment: @Dima, You are correct. I have updated my answer accordingly, but now it is basically the same as your answer :)

Comment: @User2185692, you should only use the UrlEncode method on your `Model.PICTURE_NAME` - but remember to do it after it has replaced 001 with TIF.

Comment: The name of the file is aagn%8ab.TIF but after the encode it is aagn%258ab.TIF. Thus it can't be found. Is there no way to tell the url not to interpret this symbol and just read it as normal char?

Comment: I think both me and Dima have misunderstood the question then. The problem is that your filename is already Url-encoded. When you use the filename, you path-string will be decoded into something that doesn't exist.

Is it possible that you can rename the files to their original format (without percentage-signs)? That would really make your work a lot simpler.